# What does "X people talking about this mean"?

Tags: facebook

If you use Facebook, you can see on a page's wall, it is written for example:

> 272 likes. 8 people talking about this

The number of likes is understandable, but what does "8 people talking about this" mean? Does it mean that 8 people have tagged this page on a particular day?

Answer (score 2):

It's part of the whole [Page Insights metrics](https://www.facebook.com/help/www/336893449723054/) that measures how engaged users are with the Page.

One time [Facebook.com had this written out as](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:GNQ7u5c9c-YJ:https://www.facebook.com/help/www/293874353972579+&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us):

> **How is People Talking About This defined for each of my Page posts?**
>
> People Talking About This is the number of people who have created a story from your Page post. Stories include:
>
> - Sharing, liking or commenting on your post
> - Answering a question
> - Responding to an event
> - Claiming an offer

So that [means anything from](http://searchengineland.com/demystifying-facebooks-people-are-talking-about-this-metric-96104)

- Liking the Page
- Posting on the Page's wall
- Tagging the Page in a photo
- Commenting on or sharing a post made by the Page
- Saying you're going to one of its events

Direct interactions with any of the Page's posts, events or other updates is what's counted.

Answer (score 0):

It "sounds like it calculates the mentions of a topic across the social network, when in reality, the metric only counts [direct interactions](http://www.insidefacebook.com/2012/01/10/people-talking-about-this-defined/) with a page".