# What does it exactly mean, that someone "talks" about particular Facebook Page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-like

Note: *I read [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/50980/57036) and [an answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/50984/57036) to it. It doesn't answer my doubts, so this question shouldn't be treated as duplicate.*

[My page](https://www.facebook.com/2222FacesCom) currently has `70 likes · 70 talking about this`. What does "talking about this" mean?

I have carefully checked all my up to day posts and I have exactly:

- 0 comments,
- 2 likes (my own),
- 4 shares (all my own),
- there is no question on page, anyone could answer,
- there is no event on page, in which anyone could take a part,
- no one has posted anything on my page's wall nor tagged anything on any photo.

How can *seventy people* been talking about this page, if there are no comments, no post shares or likes (except mine), no wall posts, no tagged photos and now events or questions? What does it means, that someone talks about something on Facebook? Where does these 70 talks come from?

I saw [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/50984/57036) and none of the things / events expressed there covers my situation, except for likes. My page has equal number of likes and "talks" (70). If this is the real source of my "talks", then what is the reason for giving the same value as two separate factors?

Is it possible, that Facebook is lying about my page stats (just to encourage me for another paid ad campaign for example)? Because, either I don't understand some basic concepts (I'm new to Facebook), or I have a bad feeling, that stats given me after paid ad campaign are taken from the air!

**EDIT**: I've also read these two links:

- [InsideFacebook: ‘People Talking About This’ defined](http://www.insidefacebook.com/2012/01/10/people-talking-about-this-defined/),
- [Facebook Community: What does "10 people talking about this" mean?](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10151601879070793)

But it again doesn't resolved my doubts -- how can my Page has 70 "talks", while I'm the only one, who actually did something to this page and I did it just a few times?

**EDIT:** I've asked the same question of [Facebook Community](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=1392307884359501).

Answer (score 1):

"Talking about it" generally means that, in one of his or her posts, they reference your page directly.